# Marketing Cloud FTP sub folder management

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

Can we configure the path of file drop and file import activity like /import/subfolder?
If no, is there any way to create a file transfer activity to pick the file dropped in the root of import folder into some subfolder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are possible. Here are the steps and information to achieve your request.

1) You can use a FTP client application like **[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)** or **[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/)** to manage subfolders in FTP location.

2) Once the directory is created, you can copy the path from FTP client to create a [file location](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_create_file_transfer_location.htm&type=5) in SFMC for Import Activity and File Transfer Activity..

- You'll need to select the `Relative location under Marketing Cloud FTP Site` to point to your new directory.

3) Within the automation, please select `File Drop` as the source activity type for the automation to run off on the basis of the triggered file drop.

- The UI will provide you with the list folders you can trigger the automation upon the [file drop](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_define_a_triggered_automation.htm&type=5).

> The links have been added to the post as part of the reference.